# Is EF doind something crazy?

Tags: sql, t-sql, entity-framework-6

We have this EF 6 code,

```
        var existingProduct = _productContext.Product.FirstOrDefault(
               s => s.Name.ToUpper().Trim() == productDto.Name.ToUpper().Trim() 
                    && s.IDReference == productDto.IDReference);
        if (existingProduct != null)
        {
            return existingProduct;
        }

        _productContext.Product.Add(productDto);
        _productContext.SaveChanges();
        return productDto;
```

It works sometimes and doesn't other times, it times out and we get this error,

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details. An error occurred while updating the entries. See the
>   inner exception for details. Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding. The statement has been terminated. The wait operation
>   timed out

Am I doing anything wrong ? Is it locking anything ?

It shows that its blocking something as below,

https://prnt.sc/re7h0w

Comment: Is the rest of your code locking something? Are you using an explicit transaction, or a TransactionScope? What you posted shows that some *other* connection has taken locks on that table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its a massive system, maybe somewhere else it's happening, what would be the code look like, I could do a search

Comment: The Activity Monitor already told you which connection has taken those locks. Look into the `Processes` pane for that connection and check what it does with right click, Details

Comment: BTW the query you use guarantees a full table scan and full table locks. That's because you use `ToUpper()` and `Trim()` everywhere. This *prevents* the server from using any underlying indexes, forcing a full table scan.

Comment: Why use `ToUpper()` ? Unless you used a case-sensitive collation, comparisons in SQL are case-*in*sensitive. As for trim, do you really expect to have names with trailing spaces? Why not clean them up in advance? Indexes are built using the current data values and collation. They become useless when you try to search for a value calculated by an expression

Comment: That *could* cause a timeout, in the `FirstOrDefault` call. You didn't mention where the exception occurred though. Post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`, not just the message part. You can also get that from the exception dialog box by clicking on `Copy Exception Details`

Comment: If there's a possibility of trailing whitespace you'll have to a) store the search value in a variable, just to clean things up, eg `var existingName=productDto.Name.ToUpper().Trim();` and b) change the first expression to `s.Name.StartsWith(existingName)`. This will be translated to `WHERE Name Like 'thatName%' ..`. This expression can take advantage of indexes as it's essentially a range search